# Chart primefaces não exibe eixo X

Tags: primefaces

Estou gerando um gráfico utilizando o Chart do primefaces, porém estou com problemas para gerar o eixo X. No show case deles eles criam várias listas manualmente, mas eu estou criando apenas 1 lista e varrendo um for para gerar os dados desse gráfico será que o problema é esse realmente?

```
public BarChartModel criarModeloGrafico(int ano) {
            int flag = 0;
            BarChartModel barModelo = new BarChartModel();
            barModelo.setTitle("Vendas por ano");
            barModelo.setAnimate(true);
            barModelo.setLegendPosition("ne");
            Axis yAxis = barModelo.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
            Axis xAxis = barModelo.getAxis(AxisType.X);
            xAxis.setLabel("mes");
            xAxis.setTickCount(12);
            xAxis.setMin(1);
            yAxis.setLabel("Valor R$");
            yAxis.setMin(0);

            // criar varias listas para representar cada mes
            List<Object[]> resultadoMes = null;

            // se o ano for maior que 0 pra buscar consultas no banco
            if (ano > 0) {
                    ChartSeries chartSeries = null;

                    // metodo para buscar as vendas nos meses do ano informado se
                    // existirem
                    // por isso o for irá pecorrer todos os meses do ano...
                    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
                            resultadoMes = consultaDAO.vendasPorMeses(ano, i);

                            // logica pra saber se existe consulta ou não para exibir msg
                            // pro usuario
                            if (resultadoMes.size() > 0) {
                                    flag++;
                            }
                            chartSeries = new ChartSeries();
                            chartSeries.setLabel("Vendas mes " + i);

                            if (resultadoMes != null && !resultadoMes.isEmpty()) {

                                    for (Object[] dados : resultadoMes) {
                                            chartSeries.set(dados[0],
                                                            Double.valueOf(dados[1].toString()));
                                            barModelo.addSeries(chartSeries);
                                    }
                            }
                    }

                    if (flag == 0)
                            MensagemUtil.enviarMensagem(

                            "Nenuma venda realizada ainda nesse ano!",
                                            FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN);
            }

            return barModelo;

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]